# How to model N-to-N relationships in XML without duplicating data or introducing string handles?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to achieve an XML structure equivalent to this:

```
<worker>
<name>Adam</name>
<project>
<name>Foo</name>
</project>
<project>
<name>Bar</name>
</project>
</worker>
<worker>
<name>Eve</name>
<project>
<name>Foo</name>
</project>
</worker>
<worker>
<name>Lizzie</name>
<project>
<name>Bar</name>
</project>
</worker>
```

but without duplicating the  tag contents. How can I introduce links between projects and workers in a way which would be validated by the parser and what would the required .xsd file look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD has support for identity relationships through the [keyref and key elements](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_elements_ref.asp). I was going to come up with an example but found [this one covers it well](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter17.html). I've copied the sample below. Notice that each `item` has a `@number` that corresponds to a `product` in the `products` section of the document. This is enforced in the xsd through the `OrderType` definition.

```
<order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="chapter17.xsd">
  <number>123ABBCC123</number>
  <items>
    <shirt number="557">
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <color value="blue"/>
    </shirt>
    <shirt number="557">
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <color value="sage"/>
    </shirt>
    <hat number="563">
      <quantity>1</quantity>
    </hat>
  </items>
  <products>
    <product>
      <number>557</number>
      <name>Short-Sleeved Linen Blouse</name>
      <price currency="USD">29.99</price>
    </product>
    <product>
      <number>563</number>
      <name>Ten-Gallon Hat</name>
      <price currency="USD">69.99</price>
    </product>
  </products>
</order>


<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="order" type="OrderType">
    <xs:keyref name="prodNumKeyRef" refer="prodNumKey">
      <xs:selector xpath="items/*"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@number"/>
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:key name="prodNumKey">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//product"/>
      <xs:field xpath="number"/>
    </xs:key>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="OrderType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="number" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="items" type="ItemsType"/>
      <xs:element name="products" type="ProductsType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ItemsType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="shirt" type="ProductOrderType"/>
      <xs:element name="hat" type="ProductOrderType"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ProductOrderType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="color" type="ColorType" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:integer"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ProductsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="product" type="ProductType"
                   maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ProductType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="number" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="price" type="PriceType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ColorType">
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="PriceType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:token"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks, so this the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the relationships in a DataSet and then create the schema from that.  I extended an example from my Blog here: http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/01/05/create-an-xsd-schema-without-knowing-a-damn-thing-about-xsd.aspx

```
DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet("MyDataSet");

// This can be confusing, the 'DataTable' will actually
// become Elements (Rows) in the XML file.

DataTable GolferDataTable = new DataTable("Golfer");
DataTable CourseDataTable = new DataTable("Course");
DataTable MemberShipDataTable = new DataTable("Members");

MyDataSet.Tables.Add(GolferDataTable);
MyDataSet.Tables.Add(CourseDataTable);
MyDataSet.Tables.Add(MemberShipDataTable);        

// Make columns attributes so we can 
// link directly to a GridView
GolferDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GolferID",
                             typeof(System.Int32),
                             null,
                             MappingType.Attribute));

GolferDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GolferName",
                             typeof(String),
                             null,
                             MappingType.Attribute));

CourseDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CourseID",
                              typeof(System.Int32),
                              null,
                              MappingType.Attribute));

CourseDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CourseName",
                             typeof(String),
                             null,
                             MappingType.Attribute));

MemberShipDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CourseID",
                              typeof(System.Int32),
                              null,
                              MappingType.Attribute));

MemberShipDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GolferID",
                              typeof(System.Int32),
                              null,
                              MappingType.Attribute));

DataRelation Relation1 = new DataRelation("Members1", MemberShipDataTable.Columns["GolferID"], GolferDataTable.Columns["GolferID"]);
DataRelation Relation2 = new DataRelation("Members2", MemberShipDataTable.Columns["CourseID"], CourseDataTable.Columns["CourseID"]);

MyDataSet.Relations.Add(Relation1);
MyDataSet.Relations.Add(Relation2);

// Write out the XSD
MyDataSet.WriteXmlSchema(@"C:\GolfersSchema.xsd");
```

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about .Net either :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are essentially three ways you can model the worker-project relationship. It can be hierarchic by project:

```
<project name="X">
  <worker name="Sue"/>
  <worker name="John"/>
</project>
<project name="Y">
  <worker name="Sue"/>
  <worker name="Bill"/>
</project>
```

or hierarchic by worker:

```
<worker name="Sue">
  <project name="X"/>
  <project name="Y"/>
</worker>
```

or flat:

```
<engagement project="X" worker="Sue"/>
<engagement project="Y" worker="Bill"/>
```

In all three cases if youa re to avoid data duplication you need foreign keys (e.g. IDREF values) to link to the elements holding details of a project or a worker.

Which of the three you choose is entirely up to you. Very often you will find yourself transforming from one view to another, which is why grouping in XSLT is so significant - it is often used for this kind of hierarchic inversion.